# Running StackOverflow Without ASP.NET Sessions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Would it be possible to run StackOverflow without ASP.NET sessions?

Comment: I've no idea what you're asking, but interestedy is my new favorite word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of session was discussed in the [last podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/podcast-63/), in the context of adding more servers. IIRC, the summary is "session is used but not a lot and could probably be removed if desired". But in Jeff's words ;-p

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that stackoverflow doesn't use asp.net session cookie anymore , does it mean it doesn't use session anymore ?

Comment: we use the session cookie; we don't use the ASP forms auth cookie any more

Comment: Can I know why ? :)

Comment: update: we now are truly sessionless -- all state is through cookies and GUIDs in the database.

Comment: Wójcik one of the reason is gain performance you need to be session less.